# print time on each call to std::cout

Tags: c++

How would someone do that?
for example I do like:

```
std::cout << "something";
```

then it should print the time before "something"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a simple function that prints the timestamp and then returns the stream for further printing:

```
std::ostream& tcout() {
  // Todo: get a timestamp in the desired format
  return std::cout << timestamp << ": ";
}
```

You would then call this function instead of using `std::cout` directly, whenever you want a timestamp inserted:

```
tcout() << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

Make your own stream for that :) This should work:

```
class TimedStream {
public:
    template<typename T>
    TimedStream& operator<<(const T& t) {
        std::cout << getSomeFormattedTimeAsString() << t << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

TimedStream timed_cout;

void func() {
    timed_cout << "123";
}
```

You'd be able to use this class for every type for which `std::cout << obj` can be done, so no further work is needed.

But please note that the time will be written before every `<<`, so you cannot chain them easily. Another solution with explicit timestamp is:

```
class TimestampDummy {} timestamp;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, TimestampDummy& t) {
    o << yourFancyFormattedTimestamp();
}

void func() {
    cout << timestamp << "123 " << 456 << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to chain things, why not just make TimedStream's operator<< return a std::ostream& and return std::cout? Then timed_cout << x << y, which binds as (timed_cout << x) << y, is like doing timed_cout << x followed by std::cout << y.

Answer (score 0):

```
ostream& printTimeWithString(ostream& out, const string& value)
{
  out << currentTime() << ' ' << value << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

Generate current time using your favourite [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) output format.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like homework. You want something in the line of:

```
std::cout << time << "something";
```

Find a way the retrieve the time on your system, using a system call.
Then you'll have to implement a << operator for your system-dependent time class/struct.

Comment: Homework? Looks more like the beginning of a Swiss Army Knife Logging Framework. :)